# Convert discrete sum to integral. Need direction or hint.

Tags: real-analysis, definite-integrals

I would like a direction or hint. 
I have been trying to convert the following discrete sum to a definite integral: 
$$\lim_{n \to \infty} \sum_{j=1}^{n} \left( 2 + \frac{2j-1}{3n}\right ) ^2 \arctan \left( 2 + \frac{2j-1}{3n}\right) \frac 1 n $$ 
I tried to use the formula $$\int_{a}^b f(x) \, dx = \lim_{n \to \infty} \sum_{j=1}^n f\left(a + \frac{b-a}{n} j\right) \frac{b-a}{n}$$ but I can't get the $\frac{2j-1}{3n}$ to match the necessary form $ \frac{b-a}{n}j$. Perhaps a transformation $ u=\frac{2j-1}{3} $ but then the index would not be an integer.

Comment: I hope that I did not disturb you with my "non-answer". It made me busy for a couple of hours and this is good at the current terrible time. Take care. Cheers :-)

Answer (score 2):

Notice that $2j-1$ gets the odd numbers from $1$ to $2n-1$. Consider the sum

$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\sum_{j=1}^{n} \left( 2 + \frac{2j}{3n}\right ) ^2 \arctan \left( 2 + \frac{2j}{3n}\right) \frac{1}{n} $$

which gets the even numbers from $2$ to $2n$.

Calling the first sum $S_{odd}$ and the second $S_{even}$, we have that

$$S_{odd}+S_{even} = \lim_{n\to\infty}\sum_{j=1}^{2n} \left( 2 + \frac{j}{3n}\right ) ^2 \arctan \left( 2 + \frac{j}{3n}\right) \frac{1}{n} $$

Both $S_{even}$ and $S_{odd}+S_{even}\equiv S$ are Riemann sums directly, so if we can convert both of them into integrals and subtract the results, we will be done.

$$S = \lim_{n\to\infty}3\sum_{j=1}^{2n} \left( 2 + \frac{2j}{3(2n)}\right ) ^2 \arctan \left( 2 + \frac{2j}{3(2n)}\right) \frac{2}{3(2n)} = 3\int_2^{\frac{8}{3}} x^2\arctan(x)\:dx$$

$$S_{even} = \lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{3}{2}\sum_{j=1}^{n} \left( 2 + \frac{2j}{3n}\right ) ^2 \arctan \left( 2 + \frac{2j}{3n}\right) \frac{2}{3n} = \frac{3}{2}\int_2^{\frac{8}{3}} x^2\arctan(x)\:dx$$

which means that

$$S_{odd} = \frac{3}{2}\int_2^{\frac{8}{3}} x^2\arctan(x)\:dx = \frac{1}{2}x^3\arctan(x)\Bigr|_2^{\frac{8}{3}}-\frac{1}{2}\int_2^{\frac{8}{3}}\frac{x^3}{1+x^2}\:dx$$

$$=\frac{256}{27}\arctan\left(\frac{8}{3}\right)-4\arctan(2) - \frac{1}{4}\int_2^{\frac{8}{3}} 2x \left(1 - \frac{1}{1+x^2} \right)\:dx$$

$$= \frac{256}{27}\arctan\left(\frac{8}{3}\right)-4\arctan(2) - \frac{7}{9} + \frac{1}{4}\ln\left(\frac{45}{73}\right)$$

Comment: Is it okay the variable $n$ in the limit does not match the upper bound of the discrete sum, $2n$, in the expression $ \lim_{n\to\infty}\sum_{j=1}^{2n} \left( 2 + \frac{j}{3n}\right ) ^2 \arctan \left( 2 + \frac{j}{3n}\right) \frac{1}{n}$. In other words are we allowed to use the modified identity $  \lim_{n \to \infty} \sum_{j=1}^{2n} f\left(a + \frac{b-a}{2n} j\right) \frac{b-a}{2n}= \int_{a}^b f(x) \, dx $

Comment: I am probably wrong (but I don't know where !) but my results show a limit around $6.406$ while your last expression gives $6.164$. Your solution is nice and $\to +1$. Cheers :-)

Answer (score 0):

*This is anything you want except an answer !*

"Thanks" to the containment, I tried to see how I could approximate the partial sum

$$S_n=\frac 1 n\sum_{j=1}^{n} \left( 2 + \frac{2j-1}{3n}\right ) ^2 \tan^ {-1}\left( 2 + \frac{2j-1}{3n}\right) $$
I used that, for small values of $p$
$$(2+p)^2 \tan ^{-1}(2+p)=4 \tan ^{-1}(2)+ \left(\frac{4}{5}+4 \tan ^{-1}(2)\right)p+
   \left(\frac{12}{25}+\tan ^{-1}(2)\right)p^2-\frac{p^3}{375}-\frac{2
   p^4}{1875}+\frac{67 p^5}{46875}-\frac{46 p^6}{46875}+\frac{877
   p^7}{1640625}+O\left(p^8\right)$$ Making $p=\frac{2j-1}{3n}$ and summing, this gives
$$S_n=\left(\frac{173026426}{512578125}+\frac{148}{27} \tan ^{-1}(2)\right)-\left(\frac{27172837}{1537734375}+\frac{1}{27} \tan ^{-1}(2)\right)\frac 1{n^2}+\frac{4613}{1537734375 }\frac 1{n^4}-\frac{5797}{10764140625 }\frac 1{n^6}+O\left(\frac{1}{n^7}\right)$$
 Some results
$$\left(
\begin{array}{ccc}
n & \text{approximation} & \text{exact} \\
 10 & 6.4057895 & 6.4057887 \\
 20 & 6.4062296 & 6.4062287 \\
 30 & 6.4063111 & 6.4063102 \\
 40 & 6.4063396 & 6.4063387 \\
 50 & 6.4063528 & 6.4063519 \\
 60 & 6.4063600 & 6.4063591 \\
 70 & 6.4063643 & 6.4063634 \\
 80 & 6.4063671 & 6.4063662 \\
 90 & 6.4063690 & 6.4063682 \\
 100 & 6.4063704 & 6.4063695
\end{array}
\right)$$